# Angular JS delay controller and directive initialization until data is returned from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

My AngularJS app requires some metadata from the server before it can initialize the controller and a handful of directives.   I have a service to return the data but have been unable to get the controller and directives to wait for the data.

```
myapp.factory("db",["$http",function($http)
{
  var db = {};

  db.metadata = function(callback)
  {
    $http.jsonp("/db/?f=metadata&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function(data)
    {
      callback(data);
    }).error(function(error)
    {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
  ...
  return db;
}]);


var myctrl = myapp.controller("MyCtrl",["$scope","$location","db",function($scope,$location,db)
{
  db.metadata(function(data)
  {
    $scope.metadata = data;
    // initialize $scope members with $scope.metadata for directives
     ...
  });
}]);
```

This obviously won't work since the directives will attempt to initialize using undefined $scope members before the call to db.metadata() returns.   I have tried using the $routeProvider resolve property:

```
myapp.config(["$routeProvider",function($routeProvider)
{
  $routeProvider.when("/",{
    templateUrl: "./myview.html",
    controller: "MyCtrl",
    resolve: {
      metadata: ["db","$q",function(db,$q)
      {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        db.metadata(function(data)
        {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      }]
    }
  });
}]);

var myctrl = myapp.controller("MyCtrl",["$scope","$location","db","metadata",function($scope,$location,db,metadata)
{
  $scope.metadata = metadata;
  // initialize $scope members with $scope.metadata for directives
  ...
}
```

This doesn't run as the minification friendly declaration of "metadata" in the injection array causes Angular to puke.   Removing the declaration results in the injected metadata to be undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error exactly are you getting when Angular "pukes", and why are you assigning your controllers to global variables (`myctrl`) when you could simply reference your controller as `controller: 'MyCtrl'` in your routeProvider?

Comment: Stewie, the error is: Error: Unknown provider: metadataProvider <- metadata    The myctrl vs 'MyCtrl' was a typo on my part.

Comment: How do you minify your code? Can you check if your resolve object is mangled in minified file. You could try using stringified keys in your resolve object, and see if that helps (`resolve: {'metadata': ...}`). I'm using r.js with uglify2 optimiser and it's not mangling my routes module, but that might not be the case with your optimiser.

Comment: Haven't bothered minifying yet, still in development so this isn't a minify problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the html still had

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

It's not needed since "MyCtrl" was assigned the controller for myview.html via the $routeProvider config.